# Bind button click to service method angular2+

Tags: angular

I have a `logout` method in my `auth` service. I'm trying to call it from a 
 component, however this does not seem to be working.

template

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="auth.logout()">Logout</a>
```

component

```js
import { AuthService } from '../../_services/auth.service';

constructor(
    public auth:AuthService
  ) {}
```

auth service

```js
  public logout() {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiHost+'/users/logout', {})
    .map(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      this.alertService.warning('You have been logged out.', true)
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to call a local function instead of calling auth directly from the template?

Comment: tried adding some console logs in the service method. They are not called at all.

Comment: @pengyy Why strip out the syntax highlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can returning an `Observable` from `logout` function. But calling this function don't means subscribe from the Observable.

Try to add `subscribe()` to subscribe it.

```
public logout() {
  return this.http.post<any>(this.apiHost+'/users/logout', {})
    .map(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      this.alertService.warning('You have been logged out.', true)
    })
    .catch(this.handleError)
    .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: adding a `.subscribe()` to the end in the template did the trick.

Comment: `(click)="auth.logout().subscribe()"`